# npm-mysql crashes overnight

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

***The class:***

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
module.exports = function () {

  this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'USER',
    password : 'PASSWORD',
    database : 'DATABASE',
    multipleStatements: true
  });
  
  this.query = (sql, args) => {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
      this.connection.query( sql, args, ( err, rows ) => {
        if ( err )
          return reject( err );
        resolve( rows );
      });
    });
  };

  this.close = () => {
    return async () => {
      try {
        this.connection.end(err => {
          if (err) throw err;
          return;
        });
      } catch(e) {
        return e;
      }
    }
  };
};
```

***In index i call it like this:***

```js
const Database = require('./server/modules/mysql'),
      connection = new Database();
```

***The problem:***
Overnight mysql crashes:

```js
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
listening on port 420
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (C:\Users\fedesc\Sites\borsalino\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:112:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fedesc\Sites\borsalino\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:94:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fedesc\Sites\borsalino\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1221:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (C:\Users\fedesc\Sites\borsalino\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:423:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Protocol._delegateError (C:\Users\fedesc\Sites\borsalino\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:398:10)
    at Protocol.end (C:\Users\fedesc\Sites\borsalino\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:116:8)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\fedesc\Sites\borsalino\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:94:28)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  fatal: true,
  code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I'm using Nodemon and a simple restart to the application solves the issue until the next morning (or next long period of not coding.)

I'm not really using `close()` anywhere or after anything since in the docs it says it's not needed, just `query()`.
but clearly i get a `timeout` somewhere somehow, like i should deal with the opening and closing of connection.

1. Do i need to close connections after making queries in my app?
2. Is there a way to set the timeout limit or dealing with him?
3. Am i just setting it up wrong or using wrong/outdated tool?

Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar problem, at first I ended up closing every connection (so i thought) but still it happened. I resolved it by using a connection pool.

Comment: Alright. I will check the change. Thanks. But could you please tell me what's the difference between them regarding the timeout / stay alive @PsychoMantis? Why isn't `createConnection()` handle this?